# Find probability that $X\sim Geom(p)$ is even

Tags: probability

I have to find the probability that $X$, which has geometric distribution with success parameter $p$, is even.

For all $n\in \mathbb{N_1}$
$$P(X=2n)=(1-p)^{2n-1} p=(1-p)(1-p)^{2n-2} p=(1-p) P(X=2n-1)$$

We can take sum over $n$ on both sides and get that our probability is equal to $1/(2-p)$.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation shows $P(even):P(odd)=1-p$. Use $P(odd)=1-P(even)$ to solve.

Comment: So $P(even)=(1-p)/(2-p)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use sum of geometric series.

Comment: So my answer is incorrect? If yes why it is so?

Comment: You didn't say how you got it.